# Combine js files into one and make it inline script

Tags: javascript, gulp, inline-scripting, gulp-usemin

How can i combine multiple JavaScript files into one and make it **inline script**.
Currently  I can combine into one file using gulp **usemin** but i can't do it as inline script .
I want to solve render blocking request issue.
My question is following is it possible to do it?

This is a part of code

```
<!-- build:js scripts/plugins.js -->
   <!-- endbuild -->

gulp.task('usemin', gulp.series('inject', 'less', function(callback) {
  return gulp.src('./app/index.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      //  js: [ngAnnotate,uglify]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(currentDir))
    .on('end', function () {
      del('./app/index.html');
    });
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use the [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) or [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) attributes on your script instead:

```
<script async src="app.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please can you say what is differences between **async** and **defer** and which property should I use?

Comment: Defer executes multiple script tags in order listed in html. I recommend async if execution order is unneeded.

Comment: Thanks  @AnthumChris for your response , but as I understand I can't using **async** with combined  node_modules scripts in my angular js app.